# Sometimes Unity Boots, Sometimes it Doesn't

Tags: unity

I'm wondering if someone can help me with my problem. It seems that sometimes Unity boots no problem, and then at other times, I get the warning that my PC doesn't have the proper display card (yadda yadda) and the machine boots in classic mode. Obviously, though, my card is sufficient, though, as it sometimes boots no problem.
What exacerbates the problem further is that if I try to Log Out so that I can log into safe mode, or Classic mode, or Unity Mode, I get crazy squiggly lines on my monitor and my whole system freezes. Very strange indeed.

Comment: Can you add some info about your graphics to your question?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I thought I had a link to the card info in the post: http://reviews.cnet.com/graphics-cards/ati-radeon-x850-xt/1707-8902_7-31245051.html